# Model's "spine bone" doesn't deform correctly

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

**First off, this is kinda how I want the selected spine bone to rotate the mesh…**

[image: Waluigi error]
[image: Waluigi error 2]
[image: waluigi error 3]

But after weight painting over and over again, adding more faces, and moving bones around, it always turns out something like this, the faces sorta cave in on themselves in a weird way.

[image: waluigi error 4]
[image: waluigi error 5]
I feel like i’m missing something.

Comment: The pelvis bone's direction is wrong. You have to flip it in edit mode first, then try again the weight paint.

Comment: @FFeller intial bone direction is largely irrelevant in the deformation, armature deformation depends on the bones transform and origin. Rather it effects how easy it is to animate certain movements. I have seen many good rigs with the pelvis bone pointing down.

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/